# C++ taking non-const reference to temporary: is it legal?

Tags: c++, reference, undefined-behavior

In this admittedly contrived example, an rvalue of type `X` is destroyed at the end of statement, as expected. However, the destroyed object is still accessible through non-const reference 'x'. Is this legal C++? If so, is the result undefined, or unspecified? Should not the compiler issue a warning here? I tested this on g++ 4.8.1. The compiler did not issue an error or warning (flags -pedantic and -Wall).

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct X
{
    int i;
    X () { cout << "X ctor this address: " << this << endl; }
    ~X () { cout << "X dtor this address: " << this << endl; }
    X & ref() { cout << "X ref this address: " << this << " i = " << i << endl; return *this; }
    int & get () { cout << "X get this address: " << this << " i = " << i << endl; return i; }
    void print () { cout << "X print this address: " << this << " i = " << i << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    X & x = X().ref();
    x.get() = 1234;
    x.print();
}
```

**Here is the output:**

```
X ctor this address: 0x7fff4f38ace0
X ref this address: 0x7fff4f38ace0 i = 0
X dtor this address: 0x7fff4f38ace0
X get this address: 0x7fff4f38ace0 i = 0
X print this address: 0x7fff4f38ace0 i = 1234
```

Comment: @dlf - but the const does matter. Binding a const reference to a temporary object prevents its destruction until the reference goes out of scope. A non-const reference won't do that. See: http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/

Comment: @Ferruccio You're right! I rescind my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's obviously UB and the compiler is not required to diagnose it.

In this contrived case I suppose it *could*, but not in general so there would be little purpose in implementing such a feature.

Answer (score 1):

That's *undefined behavior*.

To easily explain, I'll use pointer instead reference. (They are almost same.)

```
X *X::ptr() { return this; }
X *pf = X().ptr();
pf->print();
```

> 1. Temporary object is constructed.
> 2. Call `ptr()` and the address of temporary object is assigned to `pf`.
> 3. Temporary object is destructed. So, `pf` gets invalid.
> 4. Call `print` with an **invalid** pointer, `ptr`